# Alibaba Cloud DNS EDNSTCP

Tags: alibaba-cloud

Why Alibaba Cloud DNS does not support EDNSTCP?

I've tried running DNS checking tools and found that Alibaba DNS timeout on ednstcp. While for Godaddy passed ednstcp.

Comment: Refer to this link https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/106265.html

Answer (score 2):

Several DNS service providers, including Google, Cisco, and OpenDNS have announced that they will stop implementing DNS resolver workarounds.

These workarounds accommodate DNS systems that do not follow the EDNS protocol.

Alibaba Cloud has remediated this problem soon after the above-mentioned announcement.

> Alibaba Cloud DNS now supports the EDNS Protocol.

[Click here](https://dnsflagday.net/) to check whether the Domains that are hosted on Alibaba Cloud are compliant with the EDNS protocol or not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe it does support EDNSCTP protocol, as Ranjith has mentioned in his answer, I would like to add to it that it does support it and more information on it can be found here:
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/106265.htm

Answer (score 0):

Several DNS software and service providers, including Google, Cloudflare, Cisco, OpenDNS, and ISC, have announced that they will cease implementing DNS resolver workarounds beginning February 1, 2019. These workarounds accommodate DNS authoritative systems that do not follow the Extensions to DNS (EDNS) protocol. February 1, 2019, has been designated DNS Flag day. Domains served by DNS servers that are not compliant with the standard will not function reliably after DNS Flag day and may become unavailable.

Alibaba Cloud DNS has remediated this problem to keep your domains available.

1. Alibaba Cloud DNS now supports the EDNS protocol.
2. Domains that use Alibaba Cloud DNS will not be impacted.

Domains that are hosted on Alibaba Cloud DNS can be tested on https://dnsflagday.net/ to check whether they are compliant with the EDNS protocol. The translation of your domains will not be affected if the following error messages are returned:

[image: Stop DNS]

[image: Slow site]

Click the hyperlink in the test report which verifies that your domain has passed all EDNS tests except for the EDNSTCP test. Standard DNS queries are transmitted over UDP. Therefore, even your domain cannot pass the EDNSTCP test, your domain will remain unaffected. Use Alibaba Cloud DNS as usual.

Let me know in case of an issue